# Setup Google Analytics content groupings for reporting in behavior flow

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics I would like to use behavior flow in conjunction with Content Group(ing)s. I've set it up by the tracking code as follows:

**Content Groupings - included Content Groups**
Home - Home
List - Current, Archive
Title - Song, Album
Performer - Performer
Miscellaneous - Search, Contact

When reporting on the Behavior Flow I have to choose one content grouping (say Title), and see a lot of *(not set), song* and *album*.

My problem with this is,
1.  I would like to know from which content grouping users came to content grouping *Title* / content group Song/Album, and
2. I don't understand *(not set)* - all pages have been tagged

Is my understanding of content group(ing)s incorrect and/or did I set it up incorrectly?